# Subplots issues

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some series data, but the data graphs does not look well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def seasonal_decomposition(time,returned_values):
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Returns':returned_values})
    df.index=time
    df=df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]
    decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df['Returns'])
    trend=decomposition.trend
    seasonal=decomposition.seasonal
    residual=decomposition.resid

    plt.subplot(411)
    plt.plot(df['Returns'], label='Original')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.subplot(412)
    plt.plot(trend, label='Trend')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.subplot(413)
    plt.plot(seasonal, label='Seasonal')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.subplot(414)
    plt.plot(residual, label='residual')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    #plt.tight_layout()

    return residual
```

Graphs were displayed like below. Can someone please be kind enough to help me in fixing this issue

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you also had a data set to test it it would be better. Just try adding `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)` after you plot the figures. If the values I set won't work try to increase them. You should give them as a fraction of the axis width and height. If you give your data set I will edit my answer and include plots.